# How to read from stdin during the debug using gdb?

Tags: c++, c, gdb, stdin

I'm running gdb (or cgdb) but during the debug I need to get some data from stdin.
So how can I insert some text or numbers as input to the program while I debug it in gdb?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you attach to already running program?

Comment: How would you do it if you weren't running gdb? You can probably do something similar, if not the same, with gdb.

Comment: For instance if I use 'scanf' and I'm trying to debug the program will expect in certain moment some data from stdin. So when I step over the scanf line and enter something I cannot continue debugging.

Answer (score 2):

If you were doing it from a shell you'd do it like this:

```
gdb myprogram
gdb> run params ... < input.txt
```

Comment: And how can I enter some data without keeping it in advance in a txt file?

Comment: @Banish, you don't need nothing special in `gdb` to read from `stdin` just use `scanf`, `fgets` or whatever method you want in your program.